# Database table insert locks from a multi threaded application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, multithreading, sql-server-2008

I have a process that is running multi threaded.

Process has a thread safe collection of items to process.

Each thread processes items from the collection in a loop.

Each item in the list is sent to a stored procedure by the thread to insert data into 3 tables in a transaction (in sql). If one insert fails, all three fails. Note that the scope of transaction is per item.

The inserts are pretty simple, just inserting one row (foreign key related) into each table, with identity seeds. There is no read, just insert and then move on to the next item.

If I have multiple threads trying to process their own items each trying to insert into the same set of tables, will this create deadlocks, timeouts, or any other problems due to transaction locks?

I know I have to use one db connection per thread, i'm mainly concerned with the lock levels of tables in each transaction. When one thread is inserting rows into the 3 tables, will the other threads have to wait? There is no dependency of rows per table, except the auto identiy needs to be incremented. If it is a table level lock to increment the identity, then I suppose other threads will have to wait. The inserts may or may not be fast sometimes. If it is going to have to wait, does it make sense to do multithreading?

The objective for multithreading is to speed up the processing of items.

Please share your experience.

PS: Identity seed is not a GUID.

Comment: Are these really long running stored procedures?

Comment: Why don't you use BULK INSERT? This **really** speeds up insert process.

Comment: No, they will be just inserting and done when it came to the database. Its not heavy processing, worst case lets say 10 seconds per transaction. Mostly it will be like 1 or 2 seconds.

Comment: bulk inserts into all three tables? well, let me just say that it is not possible in the architecture of the system. This is just one scenario in the workflow. There are similar workflows that are listening for these records. Plus I will not know how many records to process beforehand. And to create all that relations in code before inserting into multiple tables will be too much. Lets just say thats not an option.

Comment: How many records are you talking about in a general transaction or even a worst case scenario?

Comment: well, it will be a transaction per item, meaning if there are 100 items, there will be 100 db transactions each involving 3 table inserts. I can't say how many items will be there. it could be 2000 or just 100. But it will always be 3 records per transaction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In SQL Server multiple inserts into a single table normally do not block each other on their own. The IDENTITY generation mechanism is highly concurrent so it does not serialize access. Inserts *may* block each other if they insert the same key in an unique index (one of them will also hit a duplicate key violation if both attempt to commit). You also have a probability game because keys are hashed, but it only comes into play in large transactions, see [%%LOCKRES%% COLLISION PROBABILITY MAGIC MARKER: 16,777,215](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/29/lockres-collision-probability-magic-marker-16777215/). If the transaction inserts into multiple tables also there shouldn't be conflicts as long as, again, the keys inserted are disjoint (this happens naturally if the inserts are master-child-child).

That being said, the presence of secondary indexes and specially the foreign keys constraints *may* introduce blocking and possible deadlocks. W/o an exact schema definition is impossible to tell wether you are or are not susceptible to deadlocks. Any other workload (reports, reads, maintenance) also adds to the contention problems and can potentially cause blocking and deadlocks.

Really really really high end deployments (the kind that don't need to ask for advice on forums...) can suffer from insert hot spot symptoms, see [Resolving PAGELATCH Contention on Highly Concurrent INSERT Workloads](http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/technicalnotes/archive/2009/09/22/resolving-pagelatch-contention-on-highly-concurrent-insert-workloads-part-1.aspx)

BTW, doing INSERTs from multiple threads is very seldom the correct answer to increasing the load throughput. See [The Data Loading Performance Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for good advice on how to solve *that* problem. And one last advice: multiple threads are also seldom the answer to making *any* program faster. Async programming is almost always the correct answer. See [`AsynchronousProcessing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.asynchronousprocessing.aspx) and [`BeginExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.beginexecutenonquery.aspx).

As a side note:

> just inserting one row (foreign key related) into each table, ...
>   There is no read,

This statement is actually contradicting itself. Foreign keys implies reads, since they must be validated during writes.

Comment: Thank you for many inputs and leads. I'll review them. In my scenario, threading is probably better than async only because my objective is not to finish the calling program faster, but to have data in the database as fast as possible. There are other processes waiting for this data. I believe this will be faster if there are say 5 threads pushing data rather than one thread doing it asynchronously. I could be wrong, but please explain if you think so.

Comment: I agree with the "insert, not read" statement. I meant to say I dont explicitly have any other read operations or anything in the middle, SQL server will have to do its thing to verify the foreign keys.

Comment: On Windows platforms the fastes applications are written by using a thread of worker pools (usually as many threads as cores available) that *never* block and do all operations async. See the papers linked from [High Performance Windows Programs](http://rusanu.com/2008/11/11/high-performance-windows-programs/) .Net implement this for you with the managed thread pool, all you have to do is play nice and use async methods. Tasks library and new [`await async`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx) constructs make this even easier to implement.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because you mentioned many good points.

Answer (score 4):

What makes you think it has to be a table level lock if there is an identity.  I don't see that in any of the documentation and I just tested an insert with (rowlock) on a table with an identity column and it works.

To minimize locking take a rowlock.  For all the stored procedures update the tables in the same order.

You have inserts into three table taking up to 10 seconds each?   I have some inserts in transactions that hit multiple tables (some of them big) and getting 100 / second.

Review your table design and keys.  If you can pick a clustered PK that represents the order of your insert and if you can sort before inserting it will make a huge difference.  Review the need for any other indexes.  If you must have other indexes then monitor the fragmentation and defragment.

Related but not the same.  I have a dataloader that must parse some data and then load millions of rows a night but not in a transaction.  It optimized at 4 parallel process starting with empty tables but the problem was after two hours of loading throughput was down by a factor of 10 due to fragmentation.   I redesigned the tables so the PK clustered index was on insert order.  Dropped any other index that did not yield at least a 50% select bump.  On the nightly insert first drop (disable) the indexes and use just two threads.  One thread to parse and one to insert.   Then I recreate the index at the end of the load.  Got 100:1 improvement over 4 threads hammering the indexes.  Yes you have a different problem but review your tables.   Too often I think indexes are added for small select benefits without considering the hit to insert and update.  Also select benefit is often over valued as you build the index and compare and that fresh index has no fragmentation.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to say inserts will take 10 seconds each. We are still in the design stage and this was just a figure I threw out there in case if there was some additional processing or wait etc. Most likely it will be instantaneous. There is no other index on this table except the PK. So, other scenarios won't apply to me. But  good to know that there is no table level lock for identity inserts.

Comment: If you are in the design stage then multi-threading is premature optimization.   You should be able to get 100+ minute on a single thread.

Comment: We are expecting a lot of load, so just preparing in advance to scale up. It could be a million records at one time that need to be processed. Then 100/sec is still 10,000 seconds which is a lot of time!!!

Comment: OK I would still start with one thread and optimize it.  If there is processing to build the insert then build the insert on one thread and perform the actual SQL insert asynch so you are building the next insert syntax while the insert is processing.

Comment: Another thought is to test loading all 100 in the same transaction.  Load each table with PageLock and all values (1,2,3), (3,4,5).  The down side is a rollback has to rollback many but hopefully a rollback is a very rare.  There is a quirk in SQL that you want the total number of values to be <= 1000 so with 100 rows if you have 10 or less columns you are good.

Answer (score 2):

Heavy-duty DBMSs like mssql are generally very, very good with handling concurrency. What exactly will happen with your concurrently executing transactions largely depends on your TI level ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175909%28v=sql.105%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)), which you can set as you see fit, but in this scenario I dont think you need to worry about deadlocks.

Whether it makes sense or not - its always hard to guess that without knowing anything about your system. Its not hard to try it out though, so you can find that out yourself. If I was to guess, I would say it wont help you much if all your threads are gonna be doing is insert rows in a round-robin fashion.

Answer (score 0):

The other threads will wait anyway, your pc cant really execute more threads than the cpu cores you have at every given moment.

You wrote you want to use multi threading to speed up the processing. Im not sure this is something you can take as given/correct automaticly. The level of parallelism and its effects on speed of processing depends on lots of factors, which are very processing - dependant, such as whether theres an IO involved, for example, or if each thread is supposed to do in memory processing only. This is, i think, one of the reasons microsoft offer the task schedulers in their tpl framework, and generally treat the concurency in this library as something that is supposed to be set at runtime.

I think your safest bet is to run test queries / processes to see exactly what happens (though, of course, it still wont be 100% accurate). You can also check out the [optimisitc concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171845.aspx) features of sql server, which allow lock - free work (im not sure how it handles identity columns though)